# Image goes out of frame when moved inside a pictureBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I zoom in on the image, I use this code to move the image inside the pictureBox.

But the problem is that when I move left, right, up or down, the image goes out of frame, as in this screenshot.

Here's the screenshot:
https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2023/46/3/1700059404-z.png

How can I improve the code to solve this problem?

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Dragging = false;
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        Dragging = true;
        xPos = e.X;
        yPos = e.Y;
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Control c = sender as Control;
    if (Dragging && c != null)
    {
        c.Top = e.Y + c.Top - yPos;
        c.Left = e.X + c.Left - xPos;
    }
}
```

Comment: What frame? The form bound? You can limit the range of the picturebox location.

Comment: I don't know how to explain it, when I move the image then it leaves white gaps like on the photo...

Comment: I can't see white gaps in the screenshot. Did you mean the window borders?

Comment: I've updated the screenshot

Comment: If `sender` is the picturebox, you were actually moving the picturebox, so its current location is where the picture is located, not where you pointed out with the red arrow. You can change the background color of the form to make it look more clear.